# Create a historical sequence in talend big data jobs

Tags: sequence, talend, bigdata

I have a requirement to create sequence in talend.
Basically records are coming from a source file.
for each source row i want to create a unique number.
here is where it gets complicated.
when a new file comes next day , the talend should pick the last generated number and then increment it with 1.
for EX:
today the last generated sequence number is 100.
tomorrow the talend should generate sequence number from 100 . i.e. 101,102,103,104.....
This means talend should keep the history of previously generated last sequence number.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So, in such a case you have to persist this last sequence value somewhere, in the target database (if any) or in a dedicated file.
If the records are stored in a database, you can also get the max value from the corresponding field using the appropriate Select.
When you got the desired value, you need to store it in a global variable, then reuse this variable to initialize the sequence with something like:
`Numeric.sequence("yourSequence", (Integer)globalMap.get("yourGlobal"), 1)`
Hope this helps.